# Jquery Animate DIV

Tags: jquery

Hi 
Am using Jquery animate function to animate div content am trying to move div to -top,The problem is not able to stop function its moving to exteme top=-10px i wanna move it to in intervals that is onscrolling it should move to -10px of existing height in next interval again it should move to further -10px on movement of scroll

Comment: $("#mvup").animate({"top": "-=10px"}, "slow");   its moving to extreme top -10px but i wanna move top -10px of exsting height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are executing the code once so, it move to -10px once you need to execute that code repeatedly after a specific interval. You can do something like this:

$(function(){
   setInterval(move,100);
});

function move(){
$("#mvup").animate({"top": "-=10px"}, "slow");
}

I think this might help you

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to scroll something along with the browser window, I presume?

This could give you a start (I hope this works):

```
$(document).scroll(function()
{
  $('yourBox').animate({top: $(document).scrollTop() - 10});
});
```

---

So I guess that's your original code.

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var frm = document.getElementById("from").contentWindow;
  frm.onscroll = function(){
    $("#mvup").animate({"top": "-=10px"}, "slow");
  }
}
```

A few pointers:

- jQuery has a `$(document).ready()` function which supersedes the `window.onload = ...` variable. It is more flexible, easier to work with, and looks cooler.
- jQuery also has a `$('#mvup').scroll()` method, so I would do away with your `frm.onscroll = ...` code.

Good luck!

Comment: window.onload = function() {
      var frm = document.getElementById("from").contentWindow;
      frm.onscroll = function(){
        $("#mvup").animate({"top": "-=10px"}, "slow");
    }

}    here mvup div content has top:350px style property i wanna move it to top by 340px for every scroll event

Comment: I would've added that to your question, but I'll see what I can do.